# String Switches Back Previous Value

Tags: java, string, multithreading, user-interface

So, this is really annoying, and an incredible magic show at the same time. So I have a global string called `setAnagram`. I'm making a GUI with Eclipse, and so what I'm trying to do, is have the user click a button, it start another thread, and on that thread it gets the value of a text field. The way I did this was to set `setAnagram` to the value of the text field.

However, that didn't actually work, and `setAnagram` had a blank value (""). So then I thought okay well what if I set the variable to `null`. Well then I get a NullPointerException.

I thought well, what if the variable actually doesn't change, and it starts the thread before it can change the variable? Well I made it so you press the button once and it changes it, then you press it again, and then it starts the thread. Here's where the weird stuff comes in. I print out the value of `setAnagram` on the first button click after it has been changed. However, when I start the thread on the next button click, it's back to the what it was initialized as ("test"). Here's the code for the button click:

```
decodeAnagramButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (buttonPresses == 0) {
            setAnagram = chosenAnagram.getText(); // chosenAnagram is the text field
            buttonPresses++;
            decodeAnagramButton.setText("Click again");
            System.out.println(setAnagram); // These two lines output the same thing
            System.out.println(chosenAnagram.getText());
        }
        else {
            titleText.setText("Decoding anagram...");
            decodeAnagramButton.setVisible(false);
            MainWindow thread = new MainWindow();
            thread.start();
        }
    }
});
```

And then to minimize, I won't add the thread code because it's kinda long, just know that all it does with `setAnagram` is get the value. Any ideas on why this is changing unexpectedly?

Comment: Hmm...you sure that you have only the global string, no member var lurking around with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>         MainWindow thread = new MainWindow();
>         thread.start();
> ```

So... you create a new instance of `MainWindow` (which is apparently a thread?!?). That means that new instance of `MainWindow` also has its own `setAnagram` member variable, right?

Try adding `thread.setAnagram = this.setAnagram;` between these two lines of code.

(Also, something about your design smells fishy, why is your main window a thread?)

Comment: Yeah - it's gotta be something like that.